# I accidentally stepped on my kitten and now she is limping my mom wants to wrap it up but Idk what do should I leave it be for now?

Tags: cats

Basically I was going to the bathroom and as always my lil mixie is running around getting her daily excrsice.i walk in the hallway and almost trip on her but this time she yelped and ran away I went do go check she out and she hid from me so I said sorry and went to the bathroom. Then come to find out she's limping lil bit and my mom is worried and think she should wrap it up just in case.i think we should leave it for a few and if it's really bad call the vet. But idk I need help

Comment: Not really sure we can help with this. A limp could be from any number of things, so it's best to just see a vet.

Comment: Definitely see a vet, most likely only a minor injury but getting it checked out will avoid further complications, potentially costly treatments down the line or even permanent damage in case it is something more serious. If the kitten is still limping an hour after the incident, it definitely warrants a visit to the vet.

Comment: In all honesty, I wouldn't rush to the vet but wait a few hours, possibly until tomorrow. If the limp dissappears in that time and your cat is back to cuddling, running and playing, I see no need to go to the vet at all. Vet visits cause stress and if this is a minor sprained joint, the vet won't be able to treat it anyways. If she still hides away, limps, licks her paw more than usual, or avoids movements like running, then a vet visit is in order.